# Partial match number field

Tags: mysql, join, match

Hey guys im really struggling at work... 
I have 2 tables with registration numbers, in table1 these numbers are 3,4,5,6 or 7 digits long.
On table2 these numbers are 9 digits long (same numbers from table1 but filled with 0's).

```
Example: table1 | table2
          134   |000000134
         2364   |000002364
        45678   |000045678
```

So i need to make a join query that match these two to get the lastname of the people who has these numbers.

I have something like this:

```
-SELECT prest.lastname,aut.registrationcode, aut.date,

-SUM(CASE WHEN aut.type like '%O%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 
                                                    'Online',
-SUM(CASE WHEN aut.type like '%D%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 
                                                    'Difered',

-count(*) AS TOTAL
-FROM prest INNER JOIN aut ON 
-aut.registrationcode like '%' || prest.code

-WHERE (aut.date BETWEEN '2019-12-01' AND '2019-12-31')

-GROUP BY prest.lastname, aut.date;
```

HOpe you can help me.

Comment: MySQL do not understand `||` operator. Use CONCAT() function.

Comment: @Akina Not by default, but you can enable it: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat

Comment: at first i used + operator wich didnt compile so i replace it with | | .
However i tried concat and the result is the same: empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that both columns containing the registration numbers have text datatype (VARCHAR, CHAR, TEXT...), you can use the `LPAD()` function:

```
...
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON LPAD(table1.registrationcode, 9, '0') = table2.registrationcode
...
```

Comment: Dude you rock! i didnt know this LPAD sentence it works perfectly, thank you very much !